# Algorithm to split a 3D grid into cubes of larger size:

Tags: algorithms

Sorry if this question is destined for StackOverflow or some software StackExchange, I didn't exactly know where to ask this.
I'm looking for an algorithm to split up a large 3d grid (cuboid of coordinates), into smaller sections.
For example, (some imagination required for this in 3d):

```
[0,3], [1,3], [2,3], [3,3]
[0,2], [1,2], [2,2], [3,2]
[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1]
[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0]
```

to

```
[0,2],        [2,2]
       
[0,0],        [2,0]
```

This would separate it by a distance of 2
I'm writing this in java, so currently have an ArrayList containing objects that hold position information (x,y,z)

Thanks,
Thomas